# How get id_token based on access_token

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Our front-end is logging in the user and retrieves the token.

Our middlelayer is a REST-API application which will consume the token.
by simply decoding the the token with

```
 JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            JwtSecurityToken jwt = (JwtSecurityToken)tokenHandler.ReadToken(ssToken);
```

we don't get the proper objectidentifier of the logged in user.
we also don;t have claims like name, email address, so I assume it's the access_token we are getting.

How can we retrieve the correct id_token when only having the access_token?

please note, we are using a 3rd party application with c#, so we are not a WEB-API, just a simple class-library

Comment: Can you share the sign in URL you're sending to Azure AD? I am interested in knowing about the `response_type` and `scope` query string parameters. In our application we use the following (among other query string parameters): `response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+profile`.

Comment: not sure, it's the front-end which resides on another server.

Comment: But you can find out, can't you?

Comment: response_type=id_token&scope=openid+profile

Answer (score 1):

Please try something like the following:

```
                System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityToken token = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityToken(id_token);
                var claims = token.Claims;
                var userId = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "oid").Value;
```

I just tried it in my project and was able to get user id back in the claims. Here my Sign-In URL looks something like:

```
https://login.windows.net/[Azure AD Tenant Id]/oauth2/authorize?response_mode=form_post&response_type=id_token&scope=openid+profile&client_id=[Client ID]&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net&redirect_uri=[Redirect Uri]&state=[User State]&nonce=[Some Random nonce]
```